# mysqli_real_escape_string other way to use it?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to know if i can use mysqli_real_escape_string on secound way. Usualy i use it like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$nameSecure = mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persions WHERE firstname = {$name}";
$con->query($sql);
```

But when i have more $_POST can i use mysqli_real_escape_string on this way:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persions WHERE firstname = {$name}";
$con->query(mysqli_real_escape_string($sql));
```

Is any differance between this two method? Actualy i didnt see anybody use secound way. Can i use secound way and is it any differance in security between this two methods?

Comment: I would not do it that way. Escaping the whole string is likely to cause more problems than it is worth.

Comment: Did this worked for you? if it ain't broke ,dont fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any differance between this two method?

Yes. The first method just escapes the `$name` string while the second escapes the entire query string.

While this is not a problem for your specific query, it could be a problem for queries, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'string';
```

Since [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) would escape the quotes, resulting in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = \'string\';
```

On a related note, I would encourage you to read about [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Mind you, they could use `foreach` loop. Quite a few examples found on the Web. Maybe even `array_map()`.

Comment: OP: *"But when i have more $_POST..."* - This tells me that they want to pass more than one POST array to the function at the same time, instead of using seperate calls.

Comment: I see. Yes, that was my note on prepared statements.